# Differences between Lambdas in Java and Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda

I am trying to find out what are the differences between Kotlin`s and Java`s lambdas. The website of Kotlin says "Kotlin has proper function types, as opposed to Java's SAM-conversions"

And I think this is the biggest difference. So you need a Functional interface in Java. And in kotlin you have function types. You dont need an extra interface.

And you can invoke lambdas in kotlin. So if you pass a lambda in java to a function, inside the body of this function you have to call the Single abstract method.

```
int method(IntBinaryOperator op){
    return op.applyAsInt(5, 10);
}
```

and the kotlin way:

```
fun method(value: Int, op: (Int) -> Int){
    print(op(value)) // You have no SAM; you can call op.invoke() or op()
}

fun main() {
  method(5) {
      it * it
  }
}
```

So i think thats a hugh advantage of kotlin that you can create your own lambdas with custom number of parameter etc and that you dont need to create an extra functional interface or currying.

Another difference and advantage is the possibility to call lambdas with receivers. I think everyone know this concept so I can skip it here. You can build DSLs, you  have scope functions.

Ah and you can pass lambdas outside the () if it is the last parameter. I think it is also an important difference between java and lambda. Its more readable.

I think that was the difference or did I miss something fundamental?

***Update:***

Thanks to @Animesh Sahu I forgot the possibility to inline lambdas

And it is possible to return the last expression inside a block. So you dont have to explicitly call 'return'

Comment: You indeed have SAM support in kotlin as well see: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2019/12/what-to-expect-in-kotlin-1-4-and-beyond

Comment: yes I know. But you dont need to use SAMs / Functional interfaces. But you need to use it in Java. So you have more flexibility in kotlin. And i think thats the point.

Comment: Yep, kotlin way is clean since it comes with native support for lambda and higher-order functions. And in fact you can inline the functions by using the [inline](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) modifier before the fun keyword to inline their callsites in order to increase performance by reducing the call stack.

Comment: One nice thing about SAMs is you can give them a more meaningful name, IdProcessor rather than just (Int) -> Int. You can a typealias to handle that, but that doesn't provide as much type-safety as an actual SAM does (possibly why they're included in Kotlin 1.4)

Comment: Could you explain why a SAM is more type-safe?

Comment: You can define a typedef and make it the parameter type for a function, but it's still possible to pass any function with matching signature. This may be fine, but sometimes you might want to be explicit about what type is passed. I haven't personally come across a need for that, though, so don't have an example.

Comment: If you have a lambda like this one (Int) -> Int 
You can define a typealias IntInAndOut. So you can only pass functions/lambdas which are Int -> Int i think. 

Dont know what you really mean sorry.